# What is this "%variance" formula doing?

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics

I'm new to a job and they are asking me to calculate '%variance' with the following formula:

$$
\frac{100\big(\frac{\bar{x} - \text{min}(x)}{\bar{x}}\big) + 100\big(\frac{\bar{x} - \text{max}(x)}{\bar{x}}\big)}{2}
$$
but I have never used this formula before and I don't see it as an example  in any variance formulas...

The resulting number can be either positive or negative and is expressed as ±.
e.g. data set 1.876, 1.657, 1.773 has a calculated variance of ±0.12%

I'm going to be training new staff using this formula, but want to make sure I'm calling it the correct name and we are using it correctly. Anyone with experience using the formula?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Interpreting "$\bar x$" as some kind of average of (likely positive) data, "min" as their smallest value, and "max" as their largest, this can be algebraically re-expressed as $1 - r/\bar x$ (as a percent) where $r$ is the average of "min" and "max," known as the *midrange.*  In this form it obviously is no kind of variance in any accepted sense of the word.  It could be understood as some kind of measure of negative skewness.  If it has a name, it would be specific to your field, because it's not commonly used in statistics. Could you tell us what this formula is used for?

Comment: Thanks whuber. The formula is being used to evaluate data sets of measured samples that are expected to be tight (we work in a lab and will do multiple assays of the same material), and if the variance is high, the data is suspect.

Comment: You need a different formula.  This one will be misleading and often wrong.  It looks like a mistaken version of the *relative percent difference* (RPD), which (for two values) is their difference divided by their mean.  It might also be a mistaken version of a "relative range," which is the range (max minus min) divided by the mean.